# Filling an NxN table with N numbers

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have been confronted with the following homework question:

> Let $M$ be a table of size $N \times N$. A legal filling of $M$ with
>   the numbers $\{1,\dots,N\}$ is one such that each cell of the table
>   has exactly one number and each line and each row contains each number
>   exactly once.
>
> Prove that for any partial filling of $M$, of the first $0 < k < n$ rows,
>   it is possible to completely fill $M$ in a legal way.
>
> Hint: Use bipartite matching

Comment: Are you allowed to assume Hall's condition for a perfect matching?

Comment: @almagest I would suppose so because the hint given is to use bipartite matching.

Comment: @almagest yes, I am allowed to assume Hall's condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a table of size $k \times N$, construct a bipartite graph whose left vertices $c_1,\ldots,c_N$ correspond to the $N$ columns of the table and whose right vertices are $1,\ldots,N$.  For each $i$, join $c_i$ to $j$ whenever $j$ does not occur as an entry in column $i$.  In other words, the neighbors of $c_i$ are the numbers which do not appear in column  $i$ of the given table.

Since the given table contains $k$ entries in each column (and so has $N-k$ entries missing in each column), each left vertex $c_i$ has valency $N-k$.  In the given table, each entry has appeared $k$ times and so is missing from exactly $N-k$ columns.  Thus, each right vertex $j$ in the bipartite graph has valency $N-k$.  Hence, the bipartite graph is regular of valency $N-k$.

The bipartite graph which we constructed satisfies Hall's condition: any subset $S$ in the left vertex set has at least $|S|$ neighbors in the right vertex set. This is because $S$ is incident to $(N-k)|S|$ edges, and each right vertex is incident to exactly $(N-k)$ edges, whence the number of right vertices needed to cover $(N-k)|S|$ edges is at least $|S|$.

By Hall's theorem, the bipartite graph has a perfect matching. A perfect matching is a set of $N$ edges which gives the entries for the next row of the table.  This process can be repeated to complete the table.  We have shown that any $k \times N$ Latin rectangle can be completed to a Latin square.

Comment: what promises that there are exactly n-k such matchings? Is that part of the fact that the graph has a regular valency of n-k?

Comment: yes.  When the valency is $N-k$, there exists a perfect matching. Remove this perfect matching from the graph.  The resulting graph is again regular, of valency $N-k-1$.  So it too has a perfect matching.  Repeat this process until we end up with a 1-regular graph, which is a perfect matching.